# AX2012 X++ Partial posting of Purch lines

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r3

I want to post the invoice of selected lines of purch order(PO) through code. need help in the code.
can anyone help me with coding ?

Answer (score 0):

The FormLetter framework has the method `chooseLinesQuery` which accepts a query of lines to update.

See [this blog](http://microsoftdax.blogspot.dk/2013/06/ax-2012-post-partial-sales-order-using.html).

Code for sales order (you can more or less substitute 'sales' with 'purch'):

```
SalesTable salesTable = SalesTable::find('your-order');
SalesFormLetter salesFormLetter = SalesFormLetter::construct(DocumentStatus::Invoice);
Query query = new Query(QueryStr(SalesUpdatePackingSlip));
QueryBuildDataSource qbds = query.dataSourceTable(tableNum(SalesLine));
// Build query range to find those lines which needs to be posted.
qbds.addRange(fieldNum(SalesLine, SalesStatus)).value(queryValue(SalesStatus::Backorder));
salesFormLetter.chooseLinesQuery(new queryRun(query));
salesFormLetter.update(salesTable);
```